# Python Embed Web Server in Data Processing Node

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a Python 2.7 project with a simple event loop that checks a variety of data sources (rabbitmq, mongodb, postgres, etc) for new data, processes the data and writes data to the next stage.

I would like to embed a web server in the application so it can receive simple REST commands, for shutting it down, diagnosis etc.

**However**, from reading the documentation on the available web servers it wasn’t clear if they will allow the event loop described above to function outside of the web server’s event loop. Ie. it looks like I would have to do something like launch the event loop using a REST call and have the loop live on an io thread, or similar.

Can someone explain which embedded server (cherrypy, bottle, flask, etc) / concurrency framework (tornado, gevent, twisted etc.) are best suited for this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a separate process for your app that will receive REST commands (use Pyramid or Flask), and have it send messages over RabbitMQ to the real time part. I like Kombu myself for interfacing with RabbitMQ, and your message bus will nicely decouple your web/rest needs from your event driven needs. Your event driven part just gets messages off the bus, and doesn't need to know anything about REST.

Comment: Interesting.  I am not sure how this would be better than just using RabbitMQ to send commands.  Can you explain?  Thanks